# How to say "common sense" in Esperanto?

Tags: translation

I want to say "use your common sense" in Esperanto. How can I translate this to Esperanto? I found "sana prudento" in Reta Vortaro, so can I just say "uzu vian sanan prudenton?

Answer (score 6):

I like *[komuna saĝo](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/sagx.html#sagx.komuna0o)*: *komuna saĝo diras al ni, ke* […]

**PS:** I found the following in the dictionary:

> ReVo - [komuna saĝo](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/sagx.html#sagx.komuna0o): prudento, kapablo por juĝi ordinarajn
>   situaciojn, saĝo (2).
>
> ReVo - [saĝo (2)](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/sagx.html#sagx.0o): prudento.
>
> ReVo - [prudento (1)](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/pruden.html#pruden.0o): kapablo trafe juĝi pri la aferoj de la
>   praktika vivo.
>
> ReVo - [komuna (2)](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/komun.html#komun.0a) ➞ *la komuna saĝo* (kapablo distingi veron de
>   malvero, almenaŭ tiom, kiom povas ĉiu ajn normala homo).
>
> PIV - [komuna (2)](http://vortaro.net/#komuna) ➞ *la komuna saĝo* (kapablo distingi pravon de
>   malpravo, almenaŭ tiom, kiom povas ĉiu ajn normala homo).

Thus, according to ReVo *komuna saĝo* and *prudento* are synonymous. A possible translation for *use your common sense* could be: *uzu la / vian prudenton or uzu la / vian komunan saĝon*.

Here is a [quotation](http://www.static.zhan.com/uploadfile/2015/04/1075026_2015042115265723k5H.pdf) (page 32) from the English version of the book *One hundred years of solitude* by Gabriel García Márquez:

> *Úrsula fought to preserve common sense in that extravagant house*

Here is the same [quotation](https://books.google.es/books?id=gZBqCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA59&lpg=PA59&dq=%22konservi+la+komunan+sa%C4%9Don%22&source=bl&ots=nhWjDf5N8j&sig=I8y0hNss8YCzgN1xJH2EwTUnW3c&hl=es&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwihjMKtr6vaAhUKOxQKHclCCKMQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=%22konservi%20la%20komunan%20sa%C4%9Don%22&f=false) (page 59) from *Cent jaroj da soleco*, translated by [Fernando de Diego](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fernando_de_Diego), one of the most important translators to Esperanto:

> *En tiu ekstravaganca domo, Úrsula klopodis konservi la komunan saĝon*

Here is the [original](https://archive.org/stream/GarciaMarquezGabrielCienAnosDeSoledad1/garcia-marquez-gabriel-cien-anos-de-soledad1_djvu.txt) in Spanish:

> *En aquella casa extravagante, Úrsula pugnaba por preservar el sentido común*

Here is the definition of [*ekstravaganca*](http://vortaro.net/#ekstravaganca) in PIV and ReVo:

> (io) Kontraŭa al la komuna saĝo, sensence stranga.

You need to know the hierarchy of importance in order to appreciate the accuracy of that translation:

God ➞ Zamenhof ➞ Fernando de Diego :p

Comment: If you ever find out what's hiding there in the dot-dot-dot, let us know. This is apparently a *Zamehofa* expression, but I can't find it in context. It could just as easily be "conventional wisdom." There are no appearances of "komuna saĝo" in the Tekstaro to get a sense for how this is actually used.

Comment: I found 9 instances of "komuna saĝo" meaning "common sense" in the Spanish dictionary of Fernando de Diego, under [sentido común](http://www.esperanto.es:8080/diccionario/iniciob.jsp?que=sentido+comun). Although the author gives no source, common sense tells me he is right.

Comment: I'm specifically asking for examples of this phrase used in Esperanto and in the wild. So far, I have only been able to find it in dictionaries.

Comment: This is an [example](http://tinyurl.com/hywpwjt) of how "komuna saĝo" is actually used by a well known Esperantist author, namely Liven Dek. Here is a translation from [English](http://www.jrbooksonline.com/intl_jew_full_version/ij47.htm) "Common sense dictates a cleaning out of the source of the disease" to [Esperanto](https://eo.mondediplo.com/article1211.html) "La simpla komuna saĝo postulas do la purigadon de la fontoj de la malsano". I think both Liven Dek and Le Monde diplomatique are trustworthy sources of good Esperanto usage.

Answer (score 5):

Just *prudento* would be fine.  You could also go with *havu la bonan sencon X-i*.

There are examples of usage here

http://vortaro.net/#prudento

Comment: For those who want to use this answer. I think you can not always translate "common sense" with "prudento". Common sense can mean a knowledge that is commonly shared and consideredd obvious. This has no relation to being prudent. Like the difference between "bon sens" and "prudence" in French.

Comment: I believe you're mixing up common sense with common knowledge. Merriam-Webster defines common sense as "the ability to think and behave in a reasonable way and to make good decisions". This matches the definition in PIV. *Prudento* is the translation given in both Benson and Wells.

Comment: The English _common sense_ is a bit of disambiguation of _sense_ and _prudento_ is just fine. Common sense (ab)used as common knowledge, would be something like _**intuicio**_.